# create a function in scheme who sort negative numbers

Tags: function, scheme

Please hellllpppp. I have to resolve that problem for school. A list of 15 items (numbers) is given. Create a function that creates a new list of negative items only. Show the amount of these. ( the program is SCHEME)

Answer (score 0):

I will not make your homeworks. But one hints.
At first, there is no need to sort the list.
There are functions in Scheme like "<" and ">" to compare numbers. In scheme these are functions with two arguments, which return true( #t ) or  false ( #f ).
(< 3 0) --> #t

You need to ask, if the sequence of numbers in the list is important.
If it is, you need to write a recursive procedure.

Comment: it's not a homework. I have a tomorrow's exam and this is the subject would look like. the sequence of numbers in the list is not important ... only the negative ones are selected and only those placed in another list. thanks and sorry but I do not know English well

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

1) this problem doesn't appear to have anything to do with "sorting"; IIUC, it's about returning a sublist of the original list. Which is fine!

2) This kind of problem is covered in depth in [section 10.1 of HtDP](http://www.htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/part_two.html#%28part._sec~3alist-produce%29).

Comment: list1( 2 3 4 5 6 7 -4 -2 4 -10) ; and the new list created listnegativenumbers(-4 -2 -10)